# USB 3.0 port not working with my HDD

Tags: hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive, windows-11, usb-3

I have a Seagate 1TB HDD with a USB 3.0 cable. When it's plugged I to the USB 3.0 port on my laptop I cannot wrote files to the hard drive. I can view the files and even copy files from the hard drive to my laptop, I just can't write to it. I beleived it was a problem with the hard drive but the hard drive works perfectly fine both ways in the USB 2.0 port. I then assumed the problem was the port but other USB 3.0 devices such as my phone with a USB 3.0 cable work fine in that port. I've tried all the solutions I could think of such as reformating the hard drive and reinstalling the USB 3.0 drivers but so far nothing has worked.

Before someone asks, yes, it is definitely a USB 3.0 cable.

*Edit: When I do attempt to write data it will start loading for just a second and then freezes at 1% indefinitely. I did suspect it could be the cable but when the hard drive and cable worked perfectly fine together in the USB 2.0 port, I assumed it must be a problem with the USB 3.0 port. Could I be wrong?*

Comment: What exactly happens when you try to copy data to the drive (when in the USB3.0 port)? Error messages?

Comment: What is the disk's model ? Have you tried perhaps another cable ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Question updated with further details.

Comment: *Could I be wrong?* Yes, definitely. The cable being "good" for USB2.0 doesn't mean it is "good" for USB3.0. Please read the comments and edit accordingly.

Comment: Which USB3 cable type is it? C? A? B? Have you tried a different cable? What about the same cable and drive, but connected to a different computer's USB3 port? This seems like a hardware issue, and figuring out which part of the hardware the problem is in shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: @music2myear it is a USB type A 3.0. works fine in a different laptop's USB 3 port. I suspected the port, but the port does work with a different USB 3.0 device connected. The only time there is a problem is that specific USB 3.0 cable in a USB 3.0 port specifically on my laptop. I don't have another cable, and I was hoping to confirm whether that was the problem before buying one.